# undefined method `member_trips_path' in ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, crud

I'm building an app where members can create a trip and I'm using the devise gem for authorization.
When a member logs in they are redirected to the trip new page where there is a form. For some reason, I can't get the form syntax just right and I'm running into an error: undefined method `member_trips_path'

This is the trip new form

```
<%= form_for [current_member, @trip] do |f| %> 

<%= f.label :where, "Where?" %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :where, placeholder: "Hawaii" %><br>

<%= f.label :when, "When?" %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :when, placeholder: "#" %><br>

<%= f.label :price_per_person, "Price per person? (Approximately)" %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :price_per_person, placeholder: "$550" %><br>

<%= f.submit "Create Trip Idea"%>
<% end %>
```

current member is equivalent to @member (this is what the devise gem does)

rake routes

```
       member_trip_index GET    /members/:member_id/trip(.:format)          trip#index
                       POST   /members/:member_id/trip(.:format)          trip#create
       new_member_trip GET    /members/:member_id/trip/new(.:format)      trip#new
      edit_member_trip GET    /members/:member_id/trip/:id/edit(.:format) trip#edit
           member_trip GET    /members/:member_id/trip/:id(.:format)      trip#show
                       PATCH  /members/:member_id/trip/:id(.:format)      trip#update
                       PUT    /members/:member_id/trip/:id(.:format)      trip#update
                       DELETE /members/:member_id/trip/:id(.:format)      trip#destroy
```

Trip controller

```
class TripController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def new
    @trip = Trip.new 
end

def create
end
end
```

Comment: Would you post your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 2):

Your routing is wrong - I think you have defined something like `resources :trip` when it should be `resources :trips`. Mixing singulars and plurals in routing is dangerous and leads to odd errors.

Comment: How do I know whether to use singular or plural in routing? So you are saying even though every member can only create one trip I should still keep it plural?

Comment: if you only want one of something, use a singular resource, eg. `resource :trip`. If you want multiple, use plurals, `resources :trips`. Either way, they should match. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources If you use singular, you will have to specify the URL to submit to, on the form - this is a longstanding bug with Rails. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769